# Calendario en primefaces solo meses y años

Tags: primefaces, calendar

actualmente me encuentro trabajando con primefaces. 
Me he topado con un detalle que no encuentro como resolver, necesito desplegar un calendario que solo me muestre los meses y los años y el valor seleccionado me lo devuelva para posteriormente utilizarlo en una consulta. 
Algo como esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente no e encontrado alguna solución a dicho dilema. 
Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Bienvenido. Para que pueda ayudarte la comunidad es necesario que incluyas lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Te recomiendo que te tomes el [tour] y seguido te pases por la página [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Answer (score -1):

hace tiempo me encontré en la misma situación. En particular lo que yo utilicé fue este componente externo basado en jQuery [monthpicker](http://lucianocosta.com.br/jquery.mtz.monthpicker/), que lo recomiendan la sección de respuestas de [stackoverflow (Ingles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609517/primefaces-calendar-component-show-only-month-and-year).
 .
Espero averte apoyado.
Saludos

Comment: responder solo colocando enlaces se considera de baja calidad, pues si los enlaces se rompen la info se pierde; si vas a usar la respuesta de otro usuario traducela, escribela aqui y deja los créditos al autor original; revisa [answer]